# How to generate correctly PDF from HTML table with full size of the table using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf

I'm trying to print a HTML Table from his class to a PDF using jsPDF but i'm getting a wrong size from the table. Is there a way to fix that or am I doing something wrong?

[Full Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P4WR.png)

[PDF Generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L8ol.png)

My .js function to generate the PDF is:

```
$scope.demoFromHTML = function() {
     var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4', true);
     // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
     // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
     var source = $('#content')[0];

     // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
     // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
     // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
     // (class, of compound) at this time.
     var specialElementHandlers = {
         // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
         '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
             // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
             return true
         }
     };
     var margins = {
         top: 80,
         bottom: 60,
         left: 40,
         width: 522
     };
     // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
     // 'inches' in this case
     pdf.fromHTML(
         source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
         source.left, // x coord
         source.top, { // y coord
             'width': source.width, // max width of content on PDF
             'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
         },

         function (dispose) {
             // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
             //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
             pdf.save('Test.pdf');
         }, margins
     );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing width: 522 to width: source.width in margins object?

Answer (score 0):

Solved just using jsPDF Autotable plugin. https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable